# API download from openweathermap with jsonlite in R

Tags: r, jsonlite

Hi it is a pretty specifc question. I am trying to replicate a case study that uses weather data and downloads it from openweathermap (http://bigdata-doctor.com/turning-rstat-into-gis-mapping-weather-germany/)

I am stuck with the intial request of the data.

```
library(jsonlite)      
url<-"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.4167&lon=13.9&units=metric&APPID=7543ec9fa0b14da9ae18f1e8facabd38"
      weather.entry<-jsonlite::fromJSON(url,simplifyMatrix = F,simplifyDataFrame = F,flatten = T)
```

I can directly access the url and it works, that I see some data for one place in Germany, but when I use the fromJSON command I always get

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Couldn't resolve host name
```

I am rather stuck what to try to make it work

Comment: Is your machine behind a proxy?

Comment: I am inside a company network. I will try the same lines from my home computer

Comment: It does work at home, so I probably have a problem with the security policy of my work network 8( any ideas what I can tell my IT department to open up for me?

Comment: I have the same issue at work, but we have a proxy that we can use during development that bypasses the firewall. In my experience, go directly to a developer in your company and ask them what they do. Alternatively, use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), which creates a tunnel using your own machine, and run in R `Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8888")`